# How to increase tests stability with Selenium RC

Tags: selenium-rc, wait

I am using seleniun RC for automation tests scripts. I use

```
selenium.waitForPageToLoad(DEFAULT_TIMEOUT);
```

but it is not stable and 50% of the time my tests fail because the next element after the wait is not found. For example:

```
selenium.open("some_url");
selenium.waitForPageToLoad(DEFAULT_TIMEOUT);
selenium.click("id=first");
```

`DEFAULT_TIMEOUT` is set to 50000.

Could someone explain how waitForPageToLoad works? What alternative I could use to increase tests stability?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Usually you may have such problem with dynamic content (Ajax calls, updates, etc.). It means that page is loaded, but some part is yet to be received from a server.

The best way (as I always do) is to check element presence:

if(selenium.isElementPresent())

selenium.click()

This approach should help.

Or you may use waitForElementPresent(). If it is not available - develop your own as:

while(!selenium.isElementPresent())

thread.sleep(1000)